# removal of elements from one queue that are present in another queue

Tags: c, queue

Suppose I have one queue with n elements, and another queue with m elements. I want to remove all the  elements from the first queue that are present in the second one queue. I can only solve with complexity of n*m.

I wonder if the problem can be solved with a better complexity.

Comment: Depends on the implementation of the queue. Is it accessible only using the standard queue operations, or can have some "backdoors"? Can we assume each operation is O(1) ? Nothing to do with C, BTW...

Comment: Look up hash sieving algorithm. It should perform in O(n).

Comment: only using the standard queue operations

Comment: Is there any assumption on the element values? (type, bounds?)

Comment: no, there is not

Comment: well...does anyone has an idea?

Comment: Well, naively you can copy the m-queue to an array, sort it in O(m * log m), then for each element in n-queue perform a binary search in this array in O(log m). So overall it will be O(n*log m). Better than O(M * n).

Comment: Is there any other way - maybe by using an useage queue?